Invalid URI: the format of the URI could not be determined in app
we are using a application in our office that i think is written with asp.net and web based. There is function in this app that makes us a printable layout. But whey i press print button in app I'm getting this error.: Invalid URI: the format of the URI could not be determined
I cannot access source code
I installed and updated freamworks and i have a .net 2 and 3 and 4.8.
Also app is using microsoft Reportviewer 2010
Please help me to fix this problem
I installed everything, tested on windows 10 and 11

While it can be frustrating to experience the problem, try first investigating what is causing it. You appear to now know even how or with what said system was built. S.O. is a Q&A site dedicated to coding questions. And there is no code in yours.

I tested in windows 10 23h1 23h2 and windows 11. This app is installed on pcs before and they are working. But now I'm trying to use it in new pc and getting this error

On  the new pc, I would check the project references on the older computer. In near all such cases, you are missing some of the reporting libraries, and the report viewer is often rather sensitive to some of those libraries missing.  You can try adding them via NugGet, but you need the correct libraries installed.
They are usually these ones:


Where i should install them? In app directory or specific folder?

You can add them with Nuget - I think that will result in the .dll's being placed in the packages folder.

The nuget downloaded then to the nugets folder. And my app doesn't have a packages folder.

Depending on the project type, then the packages folder may well not be added, but using Nuget will place them in a packages folder one level down from the project, but it really does not matter, since the .dll's will be copied to the bin folder for you.  So, let Nuget do its thing, and you should be fine.

I installed .dlls with nuget and still getting that error ...
